# align-self: flex-end not moving item to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zq5a5xu/1/)

I want author div to be at the bottom of his parent container. I tried with `align-self: flex-end;` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item .author {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content<br>Content
    </div>
    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content<br>Content<br>Content
    </div>
    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The `align-self` property moves flex items along the *cross axis*. In a column-direction container, the cross axis is horizontal. That's why `align-self: flex-end` isn't working in your layout: it's moving the item left / right, not top / bottom.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try add to .author

```
margin-top: auto;
```

You also need to remove flex-end.

Comment: Ok, but if i put width:50% it goes to the right, why?

Comment: remove align-self: flex-end;

Comment: Thanks, why do i have to do that and why with flex-end is not working?

Comment: You switched axes (vertical and horizontal). That means that self-align now working on horizontal line; To make this work you can use `justify-content: space-between;` but before that you should wrap all your elements (excluding author) into the wrapper.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a wrapper div around the divs which have to float from flex start. And the author outside the wrapper and give to `.item` `justify-content: space-between;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/0zq5a5xu/2/

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.author {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">
        Title
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">
        Title
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Content<br>Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">
        Title
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Content<br>Content<br>Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
      Author
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Hope this helps.